# How do I change this to say the body types should equal the parameter types?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use a typeclass to pass a dictionary into a function where the values of the dictionary are uniquely specified by the types of two types parameters of the function.

When I compile this code, I get the error message in the comment.

How do I modify this code to avoid this ambiguity? I would like the a and b types in the body to be the same as the ones in the formal parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses#-}

class C a b where
  a :: a
  b :: b

f :: C a b => a -> b
f a = b


-- $ runhaskell toy2.hs
-- toy2.hs:8:7:
--     Could not deduce (C a0 b) arising from a use of ‘b’
--     from the context (C a b)
--       bound by the type signature for f :: C a b => a -> b
--       at toy2.hs:7:6-20
--     The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
--     Relevant bindings include f :: a -> b (bound at toy2.hs:8:1)
--     In the expression: b
--     In an equation for ‘f’: f a = b
```

Then usage would be like

```
instance C String Double where
  a = "foo"
  b = 42.0
```

and

```
f "bar" = 42.0
```

Comment: They already are the types you want. The trouble is that there's no way to use `b` because its type doesn't mention `a`.

Comment: Ideally, `b @ a @ b` could work if enough extensions are used, like `AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeArguments, ScopedTypeVariables`. I can't test that now, though.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Suppose you have `instance C String Double where a = "foo"; b = 42.0`. What do you expect `f "bar"` to produce?

Comment: I think you could use a functional dependency `| a -> b` (if it is indeed true that `a` determines `b` in your model)

Comment: @user2297560 I'm trying to pass a dictionary into the function f that is uniquely specified by both the type of a and b, so `f "bar"` would produce 42.0. I modified my question to include this info.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks for the suggestion. I was researching that route for a while, but that isn't true in my case.

Comment: @chi can you elaborate on where I put that pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using explicit type arguments. I'm not convinced this is a good approach,
though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, 
             ScopedTypeVariables, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class C a b where
   getA :: a
   getB :: b

foo :: forall a b. C a b => a -> b
foo _ = getB @ a

instance C Int Char where
   getA = 3
   getB = 'a'

test :: Char
test = foo @ Int @ Char 23
```

Are you sure you don't have any functional dependency between `a` and `b`? Otherwise, you have to always disambiguate with explicit type arguments.

Comment: This seems to work great for my problem. I think I can compartmentalize the Type Applications into a small part of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate the problem, consider these two instances:

```
instance Char Double where
  a = 'x'
  b = 42.0

instance Char Int where
  a = 'x'
  b = 17
```

Now `f 'c'` needs to equal `b`, but which `b`? There are two instances of `C` that could work.

One solution is to use a functional dependency to enforce that the type of `b` depends on the type of `a`:

```
class C a b | b -> a where
   a :: a
   b :: b
```

Just note that you may run into some type inference issues that require explicit annotations.